# Design R C snubber for flyback converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, flyback, snubber

I have a DC/DC flyback converter and I need to design a snubber.

I already know the diode to use I just need to design the R and C value. Now, I have simulated my circuit and tweaking values on C and R I came out with C=680uF and R=2.2kOhm; the problem is they are simulated values and I've really not applied any formula.

Iknow that the diode will have a $$V_{DS}^{max}=V_{IN}+V_{C_{SN}}+\frac{\Delta V_{C_{SN}}}{2}$$ and $$R_{SN}=\frac{2V_{C_{SN}}(V_{C_{SN}}-\frac{n_1}{n_2}V_{out})}{L_df_ci_1^2}$$ and $$C_{SN}=\frac{V_{C_{SN}}}{R_{SN}f_C\Delta V_{C_{SN}}}$$

Now my Vin=12V, Fc=50KhZ, the V_DS max on the transistor should be 17V and the max I_DS on the same transistor is 2.1A (n1/n1=1 and k=0.996588)

I really can't figure it out how to put together the data and actually calculate R and C for the snubber

I put a random diode in the schematic as the one I use on the project is an MBR1045

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fS1Bc8.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is V on the primary and V on the secondary... Now I'm checking the secondary it seems bad, really

[image: This is V on the primary and V on the secondary]

This is VDS

[image: This is VDS]

And this is Vout

[image: And this is Vout]

Comment: Your snubber cannot be right at all. What is your secondary load power and what turns ratio are you considering?

Comment: To do it well, you typically want to know the leakage inductance of the transformer... If it is off the shelf it might be in the datasheet...

Comment: Honestly you should do a bit of googling first. Read this... https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.ridleyengineering.com/images/phocadownload/12_%2520flyback_snubber_design.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiAzM6-3dbpAhXDQc0KHdU5BKUQFjAAegQIAxAB&usg=AOvVaw2p6ykjCtuNK6SFRfb6q5vb

Comment: @MadHatter I got both leakage inductance of the primary and the secondary; which should I use for Ld?

Comment: It's not a snubber, it is a \$RCD\$ clamp.

Comment: You need the leakage inductance. it is the leakage inductance you need to dissipate without overvolting the switching device. This can be done with an RCD clamp, a Z clamp or an RC snubber but the leakage needs to be known

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The design of this \$RCD\$ clamp requires the knowledge of the maximum peak current your controller can set up as well as the maximum voltage you tolerate across the MOSFET. I have presented all these equations in a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202011.pdf) I taught at APEC in 2011 and entitled *The Dark side of the Flyback Converter*. The equations to determine the components values are there:

[image]

The principle of operations is to create a low-impedance voltage source hooked to the upper high-voltage rail which will clamp on the maximum excursion of the MOSFET at turn-off. However, be aware that the peak current can be much higher than the limit set by the controller considering the propagation time \$t_{prop}\$. That duration is the time needed by the controller to effectively turn the MOSFET off when the current sense pin has detected a maximum. Depending on the drive scheme, the MOSFET size, the input voltage and the primary inductance, there can be some significant overshoots destroying the MOSFET quite quickly. The capacitor value is more in the vicinity of 1 to 47 nF perhaps, as a very rough figure while the resistance cannot be too low considering the dissipated power.

People usually believe that the diode should be ultra-fast but it is little known that the turn-on time of a 1N4007 nicely competes with that of a MUR160 for instance. It is the turn-off (recovery) time that is much longer however but this lazy diode is often used in \$RCD\$ clamps of cheap adapters below 30 W because it nicely damps the oscillations at turn-off and reduces radiated EMI.

Also, surprisingly, the peak current going into the \$RCD\$ is often less than the power switch peak at the opening event. This is because part of the energy stored in the leakage inductance is used to charge the parasitic capacitance lumped at the drain until the diode conducts. By doing so, there is less current circulating in the \$RCD\$ network during the reset time. Adding a bit of capacitance across the drain-source of the MOSFET clearly helps on the \$RCD\$ power dissipation as long as the saved power is not lost in switching losses because of too big a capacitor. Typical values of 47-100 pF are often seen in commercial adapters and they also offer some snubbing advantage too.

Comment: I was just about to post a reply along these lines. The resistor obviously dissipates the energy but setting the capacitance is based upon other needs. The ΔV is chosen based upon how much ripple on the RC you want (eg 3-5% of the peak voltage).  Also if it is a primary-side sensing, you might want to accept larger ripple to allow the RC network to discharge in time for the sensing circuit to measure the flyback voltage.

Comment: Correct and the cap. value also affects the standby power big time plus inter-winding regulation. The best for the lowest standby is actually a TVS but it's costly and radiates a lot in high peak current conditions considering the very narrow spike.

Comment: With pleasure jonk!

Answer (score 4):

> *I have simulated my circuit and tweaking values on C and R I came out
>   with C=680uF and R=2.2kOhm*

Your snubber is wrong - you simply can't use a regular diode to "snub" all the reflected voltage (onto a 680 uF capacitor) from the secondary because that means you get very little secondary voltage at all. The voltage produced by the secondary "reflects" to the primary and, when the MOSFET (switching device) turns off to release energy to the secondary, the secondary voltage raises the MOSFET drain, in many cases to more that twice the incoming DC voltage: -

[image]

You can use simple RCD snubbers (without a zener) but not with a value of capacitance of 680 uF because it will accumulate all the energy and never get discharged by the parallel resistor between cycles. The idea about a snubber is that it extracts as little possible energy from what gets transferred and converts what can't get transferred to heat in the parallel resistor. Your CR time (2k2 and 680 uF) is 1.5 seconds and your switching frequency is 50 kHz and that just doesn't tally.

---

If you are aiming to get a 3.3 volts DC output (I think this would be the limit given what you have told us) then the secondary has to rise to 3.3 volts plus the forward drop of the diode in the secondary. This might mean a peak positive secondary voltage of 3.9 volts and this gets reflected into the primary when flyback occurs.

This then raises the MOSFET drain from 12 volts to 15.9 volts (during flyback) and, given that your RCD snubber needs to overcome the forward drop of its own diode (maybe 0.7 volts), the peak voltage at the drain is 16.6 volts before any voltage is developed across the capacitor. This is very tight for a 1:1 flyback transformer given that the maximum \$V_{DS}\$ of the MOSFET is 17 volts.

So, it boils down to how much energy is released by the primary leakage inductance - you have told us "k" but you haven't told us the value of the primary inductance or how much power is being transferred so it ends here (almost)...

If, the transformer were actually a step up type of 1:2 the flyback management would be easier because the reflected voltage to the primary MOSFET instead of being 3.9 volts is only half of this (1.95 volts) and this means that flyback is more manageable within the severe restriction imposed by the \$V_{DS}\$ of the MOSFET being 17 volts. However, it would be an inefficient design using a step up transformer to produce a secondary voltage so low.

---

Your pictures show an output DC voltage of 5 volts and this will have to mean that the output secondary winding has more turns than the primary winding - unorthodox but doable (but not with 680 uF).

### Simulation

This picture shows the peak MOSFET drain voltage using a 1:1 flyback transformer is rising to 19 volts and breaking the rule on \$V_{DS}\$ being less than 17 volts: -

[image]

This keeps everything the same except making the output winding have \$\sqrt2\$ more turns: -

[image]

Note that the output voltage remains at 5 volts but the peak drain voltage is just about falling below 17 volts. Maybe this is what needs to be done?

Comment: The diode is an MBR1045; I've fixed the question

Comment: @NicoCaldo No, you are missing my point - it needs to be a zener diode in series with a regular (and fast) diode to allow the natural flyback voltage to occur whilst snubbing the overshoot only from the primary leakage inductance. It seems that you are trying to prevent the natural "flyback" to occur and that defeats the whole object of a "flyback" design.

Comment: The 680 uF capacitor will just keep charging and charging until it pops because that circuit will be taking all the energy stored in the primary instead of passing it to the secondary. Maybe you meant 680 pF or 6.8 nF?

Comment: The fact is that on the exercise description says to use that diode so, I've used it

Comment: its doable but you need to know the leakage. 680u is way too large though

Comment: What really matters is the resistance value, the cap. is there to limit the ripple and make the source a stable low-impedance source hooked to the dc rail. However, it is true that with a high-value capacitor, it would take an enormous amount of time to charge and in between, the whole thing would have blown up because all the transmitted power goes in the clamp as long as its voltage is lower than the reflected level. As I said, typical values are in the range of 1 to 47 nF roughly for ac-dc adapters.